# Necessity for declaring RestEasy dependencies although bundled with WildFly?

Tags: wildfly, resteasy

According to the [RESTEasy modules in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.12.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#resteasy_modules_in_wildfly) documentation:

> In WildFly, RESTEasy and the JAX-RS API are automatically loaded into
> your deployment's classpath if and only if you are deploying a JAX-RS
> application (as determined by the presence of JAX-RS annotations).

However I don't really understand this paragraph. What does it exactly mean? As an exmaple, let's say I want to use `ResteasyClient` in a class. My IDE tells me that I must add this dependency in the corresponding `pom.xml`. But then how does that go with the above quote?

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My `pom.xml` already includes this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>20.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

When looking at [this BOM](https://github.com/wildfly/boms/blob/20.0.1.Final/jakartaee8/pom.xml) it looks as if the `resteasy-client` is already included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My IDE tells me that I must add this dependency in the corresponding pom.xml

Yes, you must declare this dependency in your pom.xml if you use the API of it, but you only need `provided`-scope, because as the documentation said, it is already included in your deployment's classpath. If you use only the standard api defined in wildfly-jakartaee8, you do not need this dependency.